# how to insert the legends inside the figure

Tags: plotting, legending

I was trying to include the legends inside the frame of a plot and I did some research, but I still couldn't get it done. The error shows "An improperly formatted option was encountered while reading a GraphicsBox. The option was not in the form of a rule." and "Coordinate {Skeleton[2]} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form."

below is what I did:

```
Show[[ListPlot[Slopetriangle, PlotStyle -> {Black}, Joined -> True], 
  PlotEMF2a, PlotEMF2b, PlotEMF2c, PlotEMF2d, 
   PlotRange -> {{-12, 3}, All}, AxesOrigin -> {-12, -350}, 
  Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"log \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \
SuperscriptBox[\(Js\), \(+\)]]\)", "EMF (mV)"}, Background -> White, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[
    LineLegend[{"C6", "C8", "C10", "C12"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row"，4}],
     PlotRange -> {{-12, 3}, {-350, 100}}, Axes -> False]]]
```

Comment: Without definitions we cannot reproduce your results. However, `Show` should only use single brackets (`[ ]`) rather than double brackets (`[[ ]]`).

Comment: I changed the [[ ]] to [ ], now I can see the figure and the legends but the legends are still out side the plot frame. Any suggestions? thank you

Comment: Include the code for all of the definitions for a **minimal** example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Show[ListPlot[Slopetriangle1, PlotStyle -> {Black}, Joined -> True], 
 ListPlot[Slopetriangle2, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashing[{0.05, 0.01}]},
   Joined -> True], PlotRange -> {{-12, 3}, All}, AxesOrigin -> {-12, -350}, Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, FrameLabel -> {"log \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), SuperscriptBox[\(Js\), \\\(+\)]]\)", "EMF (mV)"}, Background -> White, 
 PlotRange -> {{-12, 3}, {-350, 100}}, Axes -> False, PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[ LineLegend[{"triangle1", "triangle2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}, {Left, Top}],  PlotRange -> {{-12, 3}, {-350, 100}}, Axes -> False]]

Comment: Slopetriangle1 = {{1.8, -250}, {1.8, -250 + 59 + 
    59}, {-0.2, -250}, {1.8, -250}}
Slopetriangle2 = {{1.8, -250}, {1.8, -250 + 59 + 59 + 
    59}, {-0.2, -250}, {1.8, -250}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Slopetriangle1 = {{1.8, -250}, {1.8, -250 + 59 + 
    59}, {-0.2, -250}, {1.8, -250}}; Slopetriangle2 = {{1.8, -250}, {1.8, \
-250 + 59 + 59 + 59}, {-0.2, -250}, {1.8, -250}};
```

The easiest solution is to combine into a single [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
ListPlot[{Slopetriangle1, Slopetriangle2},
 PlotStyle -> {Black, {Black, Dashing[{0.05, 0.01}]}},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{-12, 3}, {-260, -50}},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[{"triangle1", "triangle2"}],
   {Left, Top}]]
```

[image]

Or since [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) is not an option for [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html), use [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html)

```
Legended[
 Show[
  ListPlot[Slopetriangle1,
   PlotStyle -> Black,
   Joined -> True],
  ListPlot[Slopetriangle2,
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashing[{0.05, 0.01}]},
   Joined -> True],
  PlotRange -> {{-12, 3}, {-260, -50}},
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False,
  LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[{Black, {Black, Dashing[{0.05, 0.01}]}},
   {"triangle1", "triangle2"}],
  {.175, .85}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It works! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to wrap the `Legended` function around `Show`.  Here is an example:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/10}];
lgnd = Framed[
   Column[{
     PointLegend[{Red}, {"data"}],
     LineLegend[{Blue}, {"fit"}]}], RoundingRadius -> 20, 
   Background -> LightBlue];
Legended[
 Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}],
   Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"log \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \
SuperscriptBox[\(Js\), \(+\)]]\)", "EMF (mV)"}, Background -> White], 
 Placed[lgnd, {0.75, 0.8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: it somehow works, but for the LineLegend[{Blue}, {"fit"}], if I have four lines that are with PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashing[None]}; {Black, Dashing[{0.05, 0.01}]}; {Black, Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}]}; and {Black, Dashing[{0.01, 0.01}]}, how can do with these four line legends?

Comment: The variable lgnd is a list of the items in your legend.  You can simply add to the list, with each item looking something like: LineLegend[{Black}, {"label"}]. I don't know how to add the dashing.

Comment: I just edited my answer to adding the Dashing.

Comment: I've got it fixed. Thanks for the help